# The correct form of the "increased demands"

Tags: grammar

I wrote the following sentence. Is the word "increased demands" used correctly, or is there a better word for it?

In addition, world population growth and increasing demands have been changing the patterns of energy consumption

Answer (score 1):

"increasing demands" better suits the present perfect progressive tense "have been changing". Or it could be written as "population growth and increased demands have changed the patterns" - the present perfect tense. "rising demands" is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage for the example provided would be “increased demand”. See the following mass noun definition for demand:

> Demand (mass noun): The desire of consumers, clients, employers, etc. for a particular commodity, service, or other item.
>   Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demand)

To my thinking the “demands” version you’re using is more local/specific (demands on an entity) rather than the global/generic (desire for something).

You can also find plenty of examples of the “increased demand” online. Here’s a paper I found which uses it in the identical context you have:

> ”The UN’s Food and Agriculture Organization (FAO) and World Food Program (WFP) called on the world to double food production by 2050 to meet rising demand, not just from a growing population but one that is expected to consume more meat”
>
> Link: [Can We Feed the World in 2050?
>   A Scoping Paper to Assess the Evidence](http://www.ase.tufts.edu/gdae/Pubs/wp/13-04WiseFeedWorld2050.pdf)